# indexNumber in for-loop does not increase

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I get the idea of if the ***if condition is wrong*** the if case won't be executed, but the ***for loop will still continue***. But somehow I'm stucked upon this simple problem.

```
int divisorA[20]={0},indexA=0,a=42;

    for (int i =1;i<a+1;++i){
        if (a % i == 0){
            divisorA[indexA] = i;
            ++indexA;
            printf("%d %d\n",divisorA[indexA],indexA);
        }

   }
```

Output

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8
```

Desired

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
6 4
7 5
14 6
21 7
42 8
```

Comment: You are printing `divisorA[indexA]` *after*  you have incremented `indexA`, so you are accessing the next element in the array (which you have initialized to 0)

Comment: You increase `indexA` _before_ you print and hence read array members that are not set yet.

Comment: Exchange the lines `++indexA;` and `printf("%d %d\n",divisorA[indexA],indexA);`

Comment: oh that was dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You at first increased the index and only after that you outputted the array element at the index position that will not be yet set.

```
        ++indexA;
        printf("%d %d\n",divisorA[indexA],indexA);
```

Write

```
        ++indexA;
        printf("%d %d\n",divisorA[indexA-1],indexA);
```

Pay attention to that indices in C start from 0.

Answer (score 2):

An easy one, you are printing the indexed array value /after/ you have incremented the index, so it pronts the next unpopulated slot, a zero.